# How can I animate the dismissal of a UITableView swipe-to-delete button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, animation

As is done in the iPhone Mail app, I would like have the "Delete" button which appears on swiping an editable table cell from right to left to *animate* when it is dismissed (by way of tapping elsewhere than the Delete button on the `UITableViewCell`). Instead, my Delete button immediately disappears when it is dismissed.

To invoke the Delete button on swiping a table cell in the first place, I have added (to the class which is the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` for the `UITableView` in question):

```
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //add code here for when you hit delete
    }       
}
```

Is there something I might add to this which will handle the animation of the Delete button when it is dismissed? Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem, just now found out that there is some problem when we have empty cell.textLabel.text. Try add in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath:
{
    {...} // omitted code
    cell.textLabel.text = @"whatever";          
    cell.textLabel.hidden = YES;
}
```

With this swipe button dismiss proper, but WHY?
PS: tested with custom cells and built i.n

Comment: This fixed my issue with animation of delete button dismissal on a custom cell.

Comment: Did it for me as well! In my table cells I use custom views only, and the delete dismiss animation was not working. But adding a simple string to the default cell textlabel did the trick. Really strange. Thankyou!

Comment: I still have no idea why this is but I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: Wow I thought Apple just short changed us on the animation.. Great find! I didn't think there was going to be any solutions. Thanks a lot!! This should be the accepted answer @MCIsAFatalError

Comment: I had to use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764023/ios-uitableview-cancel-delete-row-button-animation-works-only-accessory-vi

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to animate the dismissal manually, it works the same way as invoking it so not sure why it is behaving differently in your app.

Are you using custom cells by any chance? As a thought for you to try, change the `shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:` method to return NO and see if it changes anything. The only thing I can think of is that your content indentation is interfering with the delete button area in a way that the animation can't be performed or is not behaving as it should.

`- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I've just ran into this issue as well.  I have a series of tableViews and I noticed that some of them have the proper dismissal fade and others don't.

It seems the difference is a UITableViewCellAccessory.  If this is set to anything other than UITableViewCellAccessoryNone then you get the proper animation.  I think this might be a bug.  Can anyone else confirm this behavior?

Comment: May be too late, but I got the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
**> //MARK:-Tableview delete to left in swift without any tag By using Button Action**  
    let point = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tableView)
            guard let indexpath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point) else {return}
            stringArr.remove(at: indexpath.row)
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: indexpath.row, section: 0)], with: .left)
            tableView.endUpdates()
```