# iOS - UITableView - cancel delete row - button animation works only accessory view is present

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

**Overview (Edited)**

I have UITableView, when I swipe, the delete button appears, when I touch else where, the delete button just disappears without any animation.

**With Accessory**

- If I add an accessory (Disclosure Indicator), when the delete is cancelled, the delete button vanishes with animation.

**Without Accessory**

- If I remove the accessory from the table view cell, then delete cancellation doesn't show any animation.

**Question**

- I don't want the accessory but i want the delete cancellation animation, is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: I would suggest filing this as a bug with Apple....

Comment: thanks, i just filed a bug, in the meantime, pls let me know if there is any work around

Comment: hi, I have a similar problem. but mine is not an accessory view. it is just a label that the delete button can cover when it was being shown. did you find a solution for that?

Comment: If your concern is regarding the animation when the delete is cancelled, then I haven't found a solution for it. (adding an accessory view caused the delete cancellation animation to appear). If your concern is about the UILabel partly covered when the delete button appears, then do the following (hide and unhide label): `- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    if(editing && self.editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
 label1.hidden = YES;
    else 
 label1.hidden = NO;
    }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS 6 this "bug" still exists. There are 2 ways to workaround this problem:

### Solution 1:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //[...]
    cell.accessoryView = [UIView new];
    //[...]
}
```

### Solution 2

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.accessoryView = [UIView new];
}
```

This way when "remove row" is canceled, the button disappears with animation.

Comment: Thanks a ton !! smart and simple solution

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using the cell.textlabel property, try to set it to something and then hide it.

```
cell.textlabel.text = @"something";
Cell.textlabel.hidden = YES;
```

It should work