# How to hide delete button of UITableView with animation in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, hide, swipe

I am working with the kind of notes app and I wanted to add the option to swipe-to-delete (like the iPhone's default notes app). I implemented the following two table view methods..

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        //Action to delete value of the cell
    }
}
```

Everything works well except an animation. Showing the delete button on swipe action happens with an animation while hiding it (by tapping or scrolling table view) does not happens with the animation. The delete button was just disappeared immediately.

Can I show the hiding process of the delete button with animation?

Comment: When you swipe then may be your table reload.just check it.

Comment: No, the table view does not reloaded while swipe the cell. Only the canEditRowAtIndexPath: method was called in swipe action.

Comment: The problem is, cell.textLabel.text should hold some value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981953/how-can-i-animate-the-dismissal-of-a-uitableview-swipe-to-delete-button

Answer (score 1):

For fully control on editing in your custom cell, you should override willTransitionToState method in your UITableViewCell subclass and check state mask

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{
    NSString *logStr = @"Invoked";
    if ((state & UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask)
        != 0) {
        // you need to move the controls in left
        logStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@
                  %@",logStr,@"UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask"];
    }
    if ((state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)
        != 0) {
        // you need to hide the controls for the delete button
        logStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@
                  %@",logStr,@"UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask"];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",logStr);
    [super willTransitionToState:state];
}
```

**EDIT:**

Did you try:

setEditing:animated:
Toggles the receiver into and out of editing mode.

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
  Parameters
  editing
  YES to enter editing mode, NO to leave it. The default value is NO .
  animated
  YES to animate the appearance or disappearance of the insertion/deletion control and the reordering control, NO to make the transition immediate.
  Discussion
  When you call this method with the value of editing set to YES, and the UITableViewCell object is configured to have controls, the cell shows an insertion (green plus) or deletion control (red minus) on the left side of each cell and a reordering control on the right side. This method is called on each visible cell when the setEditing:animated: method of UITableView is invoked. Calling this method with editing set to NO removes the controls from the cell.

Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
See Also
  @property editing
Declared In
UITableViewCell.h

Comment: So, the hiding animation is not a default one?

Comment: In my case, there is no red minus. Did you see the iPhone notes app? Only just a red color button with name "Delete" will appear on the right end of the swiped cell.